# Display Swift Snippets in Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I want to display swift code in my WordPress site but I have not found any useful plugin. For now I use *Crayon Syntax Highlighter* but there isn't a theme for the code that make it look like on the apple developer website. 
For example this is how it looks on the apple site: 
[image: code sample on developer.apple.com]

And this is what it looks with the plugin:
[image: output with the plugin]

is there an easy way to display the code like on the apple site? Further I had a look into the article Crayon Theme Editor from the developer of the site but since the pictures are gone it's not very useful.

I also hope that this is the right place to ask for something like this.

Comment: If you're talking about font and colors, this is just a CSS issue. Best move would be to enqueue a new style sheet and dequeue the plugin's stylesheet  (s) on posts where you are displaying Swift code. That is assuming the plugin offers no built in way to edit them, of course.